# MYSQL IF Muestra true y false a la vez

Tags: mysql

estoy intentando añadir al código mysql un if, pero cuando lo hago me devuelve tanto el valor true como el false,también he probado con when pero me pasa lo mismo, aquí pongo el código y un ejemplo:

```
BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT
concat(A.codigoArmador, ' - ', A.armador) as nombreBarco
,IF(CC.ivaEspecifico=1, @porcentajeComision := ROUND( (SELECT PC1.valor
FROM precios_configuracion PC1
WHERE PC1.clave = 'ivaEspecifico'
AND PC1.fechaEntradaVigor = ( SELECT MAX(PC11.fechaEntradaVigor)
FROM precios_configuracion PC11
WHERE PC11.clave = 'ivaEspecifico'
AND PC11.fechaEntradaVigor <= p_FechaInicio)
),2),@porcentajeComision := ROUND( (SELECT PC1.valor
FROM precios_configuracion PC1
WHERE PC1.clave = 'comision'
AND PC1.fechaEntradaVigor = ( SELECT MAX(PC11.fechaEntradaVigor)
FROM precios_configuracion PC11
WHERE PC11.clave = 'comision'
AND PC11.fechaEntradaVigor <= p_FechaInicio)
),2))  as porcentajeComision
, @porcentajeIva := ROUND( (SELECT PC1.valor
FROM precios_configuracion PC1
WHERE PC1.clave = 'iva'
AND PC1.fechaEntradaVigor = ( SELECT MAX(PC11.fechaEntradaVigor)
FROM precios_configuracion PC11
WHERE PC11.clave = 'iva'
AND PC11.fechaEntradaVigor <= p_FechaInicio)
),2) as porcentajeIva
, @totalVenta := ROUND( (SELECT ifnull(SUM(importeVenta),0) FROM cartasCuenta AS CC2 WHERE fecha BETWEEN p_FechaInicio AND p_FechaFin AND CC2.IdArmador = A.IdArmador),2) as totalVenta
, @comision := ROUND(CONVERT(@porcentajeComision, decimal(12,2)) * CONVERT(@totalVenta, decimal(12,2)) / 100 ,2) as comision
, @iva := ROUND(CONVERT(@comision, decimal(12,2)) * CONVERT(@porcentajeIva, decimal(12,2)) / 100,2) as iva
, ROUND(CONVERT(@comision, decimal(12,2)) + CONVERT(@iva, decimal(12,2)), 2) as total
FROM
armadores A, cartascuenta CC
ORDER BY A.codigoArmador;
END
```

Ejemplo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK6Za.png

Comment: ¿A qué valor `TRUE` y `FALSE` te refieres exactamente? Si no lo explicas en el enunciado nos obligas a analizar todo tu código tratando de adivinar lo que hace y tratando de adivinar el problema. ¿No es más simple que nos digas *me devuelve tal cosa en tal sitio*?

Comment: Si disculpe, a partir de la linea 4 empiezo un IF para que si el valor es igual a 1 haga un cálculo(esto sería el true), de lo contrario en la línea 11 empieza el false lo que haría otro cálculo.

Comment: ¿Has verificado directamente en el SGBD las sub-consultas de cada IF para comprobar que arrojan los valores que esperas?